# Drive Search does not locate .docx and .txt files

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory

```
void findFile(const std::wstring &directory, wstring inputSearch)
{ // , char *currDrives){ //function for algorithm to search your computer to find what you want to load

    //wcout << directory << endl;

    //cout << "In" << endl;

wstring search = inputSearch;

std::wstring tmp = directory + L"\\*";

size_t found;

WIN32_FIND_DATAW file;
HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(tmp.c_str(), &file);
if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> directories;

    do
    {
        found = tmp.find_last_of(L"/\\");

        if (tmp.substr(found + 1) == inputSearch) {

            cout << "Found File" << endl;
            continueSearching = false;
            foundFilePath = tmp;

        }

        if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if ((!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".."))) {
                continue;
            }

        }

        tmp = directory + L"\\" + std::wstring(file.cFileName);
        bruteForceComp++;
        //std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;

        if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)

            directories.push_back(tmp);

    } while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &file) && continueSearching == true);

    FindClose(search_handle);

    for (std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = directories.begin(), end = directories.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {

        findFile(*iter, inputSearch);

    }
}

}
```

We have this function that searches all sub-directories within a certain drive. We compare this to a search term that is inputted by the user. (The drive and the search term are the two parameters passed into the function) We locate .exe files fine and a bunch of other files, but when we try to locate a .docx or .txt file they do not appear. Any help with finding why would be appreciated. We're somewhat stumped.

Thanks!

foundFilePath is a static wstring by the way. It is where we store the matching path to the search term. Search term is inputted as word.exe or yay.docx also.

Comment: Perhaps try a case-independent comparison.

Comment: If nothing else you'll always skip the last item in a folder because of where you're comparing against the search string.

Comment: NTFS is case-insensitive (and case-preserving). Replace `tmp.substr(found + 1) == inputSearch` with `lstrcmpiW( tmp.substr(found + 1).c_str(), inputSearch.c_str() ) == 0`, and fix the bug noted by Jonathan Potter.

Comment: Note that `file.cFileName` doesn't include directory. It can be, for example, "yay.docx". You can just check `if(lstrcmpiW(file.cFileName, inputSearch.c_str())==0)` then print out your `tmp` variable which is the full path of the file.